# Trying to render different layout but getting nomethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Trying to render different layout by doing this:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  render layout "locations"
```

Have a corresponding locations.html.erb file in Layouts and a Locations folder containing index and show files.

My locations layout files is simply this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>locations layout</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui menu">
            <%= link_to "Counties", counties_path, :class => "active item"%>
            <%= link_to "About Us", about_path, :class => "item"%>
        </div>
        <%= yield %>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error and don;t know why:

```
undefined method `render' for LocationsController:Class
```

All my routes are also listed in the error message and are as follows:

```
 resources :counties do
   resources :locations
 end


 root 'home#index'
 get '/about' => "home#about"
 get "/:location_name_with_prefix" => "locations#show_by_location_name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call

```
layout "locations"
```

so, remove the 'render'

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put render keyword. Only use 
`layout 'locations'` and it should work

Comment: Thanks too @LHH I didn;t know how to split an answer since they were both the same and both correct!